# PHP AJAX Responses, how can i add different conditions?

Tags: php, jquery

I want to be able to set the following:

1) If the email already exists to return an error
2) If successful to return an error
3) if error to return error

At the moment it works, but allows you to add same email address and sends successful response but need to add one for existing email

```
$('form').submit(function(){

// check if passwords match; you might want to do more thorough validation
    var hasError = false;
    var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
    var emailaddressVal = $("#email").val();
    if(emailaddressVal == '') {
            $("#email").after('<span class="error">Please enter your email address.</span>');
            hasError = true;
    }

    else if(!emailReg.test(emailaddressVal)) {
            $("#email").after('<span class="error">Enter a valid email address.</span>');
            hasError = true;
    } else if(hasError == false) {
            // make ajax post request and store the response in "response" variable
     $.post('submit.php', $(this).serialize(), function(response){

         // process response here (assume JSON object has boolean property "ok"
         if(response.ok==true){
             // sweet, it worked!
             alert('OK!');
         }else{
             // handle error
             alert('Ooops');
         }
     }, 'json');
    }

    // stop the form from being submitted
return false;
});
```

And the php is:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root",""); //Replace with your actual MySQL DB Username and Password
if (!$con) { die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); } 
mysql_select_db("table", $con); //Replace with your MySQL DB Name

$first_name=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['firstname']); 
$last_name=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lastname']); 
$email=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']); 

$sql="INSERT INTO email_list (first_name,last_name,email) VALUES ('$first_name','$last_name','$email')"; 

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con)) { die('Error: ' . mysql_error()); } 
echo "The form data was successfully added to your database."; 
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate refer this link you can do it easily.

Comment: please.. dont use `mysql_*`! it's **deprecated**. Use **`PDO`**! (or `mysqli_*`)

Comment: and.. real escaping? [nice way to got all data lost](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jquery

```
$('form').submit(function(){

// check if passwords match; you might want to do more thorough validation
    var hasError = false;
    var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
    var emailaddressVal = $("#email").val();
    if(emailaddressVal == '') {
            $("#email").after('<span class="error">Please enter your email address.</span>');
            hasError = true;
    }

    else if(!emailReg.test(emailaddressVal)) {
            $("#email").after('<span class="error">Enter a valid email address.</span>');
            hasError = true;
    } else if(hasError == false) {
            // make ajax post request and store the response in "response" variable
     $.post('submit.php', $(this).serialize(), function(response){

         // process response here (assume JSON object has boolean property "ok"
         if(response.ok=='0'){
             alert('required fields empty');
         }else if(response.ok=='1'){
               alert('email already exists');
         }
else if(response.ok=='2')
{
alert('thankyou for your input');
}
     }, 'json');
    }

    // stop the form from being submitted
return false;
});
```

php code

```
    <?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root",""); //Replace with your actual MySQL DB Username and Password
    if (!$con) { die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); } 
    mysql_select_db("table", $con); //Replace with your MySQL DB Name

    $first_name=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['firstname']); 
    $last_name=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lastname']); 
    $email=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']); 

    if(empty($first_name) || empty($last_name) || empty($email) ) {

        echo json_encode( array('ok'=> '0' ) );
        exit();
    }

    $sql="Select * from email_list where email='".$email."' ";
    $sqll=mysql_query($sql) or die($sql."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());
    $data=mysql_fetch_array($sqll);
    if($data['email']) {

        echo json_encode( array('ok'=> '1' ) );
        exit();

    }

    $sql="INSERT INTO email_list (first_name,last_name,email) VALUES ('$first_name','$last_name','$email')"; 
mysql_query($sql) or die($sql."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());
    $value = mysql_insert_id() > 0;
    if($value)
    echo json_encode( array('ok'=> '2' ) );
    mysql_close($con);
    exit();
    ?>
```

Comment: i get: Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean

Comment: check now,if my select query isn't proper it will show you the exact error.

Comment: Now you'll also get the query echoed in case of error so you can directly run it in the database and check if its correct.

Comment: missed the mysql_query statement.

Answer (score 2):

Just check for the email in the db before u add.
Hope This Helps.

```
    <?php
    $first_name=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['firstname']); 
    $last_name=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lastname']); 
    $email=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']); 
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM email_list WHERE `email`='$email'";
    $res= @mysql_query($sql);
    if(@mysql_num_rows($res)>0)
    {
      echo "Email Already Exists" ;

    }
    else
{
 $sql="INSERT INTO email_list (first_name,last_name,email) VALUES ('$first_name','$last_name','$email')"; 

    if (!mysql_query($sql,$con)) { die('Error: ' . mysql_error()); } 
    echo "The form data was successfully added to your database."; 
  }
    ?>
```

Comment: I need to through the error to the html page with JS though, so w ith this im half way there so thank you! :)

Comment: You should do the insert only if mysql_num_rows($res)<1, this way you insert email only if it already exists.

Comment: @Anwar nice? I dont think so: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string

Comment: i got: Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean

Comment: Put quotes around email: 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM email_list WHERE `email`='".$email."'";

Answer (score 2):

```
$sql="SELECT email FROM email_list WHERE email = '$email'";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $con) or die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
  // Error - Email already exists
   echo "Error: The email address already exists."; 
} else {
   $sql="INSERT INTO email_list (first_name,last_name,email) VALUES ('$first_name','$last_name','$email')"; 

   if (!mysql_query($sql,$con)) { die('Error: ' . mysql_error()); } 
   echo "The form data was successfully added to your database."; 
}

mysql_close($con);
```

I have added a check to see if the email address already exists, and output an error if it does.  There are also error outputs for mysql errors.

If you need the output to be formatted in a certain way, use JSON.  But the above should get you started.

Comment: worked great! now i just need to work out with JSON responses so i can return the errors to the page

Answer (score 1):

just add following line in end of you php file

```
$value = mysql_insert_id() > 0;

echo json_encode( array('ok'=> $value ) );
```

Comment: and what? getting `ok` when u'll insert another record with email already existed in table?

Comment: you need to check before execute insert query like

Comment: $sql="select count(*) idavail email_list where email = '".$email."'"; 
$result= mysql_query( $sql );

Comment: `you`? not me:) author of questin. and thats not so easy, as you wrote here. before insert u may: 1. check if this field already exists... or 2. set this row unique.

Comment: answer isnt correct for now. even not close to be truth. edit?

Comment: $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result );
if( $row['idavail'] > 0 ){
    echo json_encode(array('ok' => false ));
    exit;
}

Comment: no this is correct first then you can say it is wrong or correct

Comment: and don't echo anything else

Comment: like `echo "The form data was successfully added to your database."; `